# Why is my render all white?

Tags: rendering

I'm a new user of Blender. I started to learn it about 1 week ago. I watch channel BlenderGuru on Youtube and it is clear for me how to make a mesh and add modifiers, but I have a problem with render. It is always looks white. I'll upload a screenshot, so you can see what's happened. I tried to move the light and even delete it, but it is always looks the same. Could you please help me to fix this problem?[image]

Answer (score 5):

The Donut Tutorial uses Cycles Render Engine. You are on Blender Render Engine. You can change it in the dropdown at the top.